# How to automatically add <img> height and width in Visual Studio?

Tags: html, visual-studio, height, width, image

When I drop an html image onto my page (vs2005) the height and width attributes are not specified.

Do I really have to edit the html by hand to add these? Or is there an automatic method?

Answer (score 1):

Just drag it into the design view.

If you are using Visual Studio 2010 or higher make sure you tick "Use width and height attributes for image instead of CSS" option under HTML Designer -> CSS Styling:

[image]

Comment: @Pavel: This is a screenshot from VS 2005 as stated in the question? Really?

Comment: @Jon Oops, no. It is VS 2010. Let's leave it since it could be useful to someone.

Answer (score -1):

You can template a section of code and add an item in the toolbox for it.

Type the code you want as your template in the editor, select it, then drag and drop to the toolbox. You can then drag and drop from the toolbox into any source code you want.

Edit: This works for any text in Visual Studio, not just HTML.

Comment: how would this automatically insert the image height and width in an HTML tag?

Comment: If you include the height and width tags in the text you drop into the toolbox, it will be reproduced when you drag and drop from the toolbox onto your source code. There isn't any trick to it -- it just copy/pastes what you write. There's no mechanism that I know of to insert default attributes when dropping a control onto your code.